# Transforming Excel worksheet with multiple table in FME

Tags: excel, etl, esri, fme

I need to transform Excel files to ESRI FileGDB using FME.
The problem is that my excel worksheets contains more than one table.

Example: At row 1, I have the attributes of the first table. Row 2 to 4 contains the values.
At row 6 I have the attributes of the second table. 45 next rows are the values.
And the same thing for the third table.

These rows can change. I could have the attributes of the second table at any row.

I think the best solution would be to have a process that split the .xls file in three different files so I can transform them directly into ESRI format.

Is there a transformer that could perform this task or should I code it myself in Python?

PS: This process will be called from a REST Service so I can't do this manually. Also, the columns name will always be the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FME reads the Excel rows in order, so I would add a `Counter` transformer after reading the Excel file.

The column names don't change, so you could check at which row (number given by the `Counter`) the new table begins.

Then is just a matter of filtering the features with a `TestFilter`.